# Timing a vacation in/around Milan, at the end of September

Tags: italy, planning, itineraries, milan, timetables

It seems like I'm going to attend a conference in Milan between September 29th and October 1st of this year. I'm thinking of extending my vacation by 3-4 days, and play tourist for a while; but - I'm not sure whether to prefer taking those extra days before Sep 29th, after the Oct 1st, or half-and-half.

My question: What considerations would I make to help me decide? In particular, is it more likely I'll find interesting things going on in the city during the last week of September vs the first week of October? (Other than the [LibreOffice conference](https://conference.libreoffice.org/2022/) of course)? I'm guessing there's no difference in the weather forecasts so far in advance, so that's not a consideration... what can I take into account?

Comment: I was in Northern Italy (more to the east) mid September a few years ago and it was clearly the end of the tourist season out there. (So I would push for before and I would keep it in one block, not split up.)